# A dense NP complete language implies P=NP

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability

We say that the language $J \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$ is *dense* if there exists a polynomial $p$ such that $$ |J^c \cap \Sigma^n| \leq p(n)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}.$ In other words, for any given lenght $n$ there exist only polynomially many words of length $n$ that are not in $J.$

The problem I am currently studying asks to show the following

> If there exist a dense $NP$-complete language then $P = NP$

What the text suggest is to consider the polynomial reduction to $3$-$SAT$ and then construct an algorithm that tries to satisfy the given $CNF$ formula while also generating elements in $J^c.$

What I am wondering is

> Is there a more direct proof? Is this notion known in a more general setting?

Comment: There is a related notion of *sparse* languages, in which the condition is just the opposite: $|J \cap \Sigma^n| \leq p(n)$.

Comment: Check out [Mahaney's theorem](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2011/09/mahaneys-theorem.html).

Comment: @PålGD Turn into an answer? (assuming the argument carries over to dense languages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a nice homework problem about Mahaney's theorem.

Note that the complement of a "dense" language is a sparse language. Moreover if a language is  $\mathsf{NP}$-complete its complement is $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete.

If there is a "dense" $\mathsf{NP}$-complete language, there is a [sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_language) $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete language.

Mahaney's theorem tells us that there is no sparse $\mathsf{NP}$-complete language unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$.

We can adopt the proof to show that there is no sparse $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete language unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{coNP}$ which is equivalent to $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ (since $\mathsf{P}$ is closed under complements).

In summary, the answer is no unless $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$. Note that if $\mathsf{P}=\mathsf{NP}$ then every nontrivial language is $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

ps:
You may want to try the following and then use Mahaney's theorem: there is a sparse $\mathsf{NP}$-complete set iff there is a sparse $\mathsf{coNP}$-complete set.
However I doubt that a proof for this statement would be much easier than a proof for Mahaney's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned above according to **[Mahaney's theorem](http://www.villesalo.com/OtEoDoSNPHL.pdf)**. Sparse and dense languages could not be $NP-Hard$  unless  $P=NP$.

The mentioned draft contains complete proof.

Comment: This does not give more than the comment (which is not even yours). Please elaborate to make a proper answer out of this post.

Comment: @Raphael: It is a proper answer.  Did you check the link?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto: Answers consisting only of a link are generally considered bad on SE; see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers).

Comment: @Raphael: The question answered was solved before in literature. The link contains whole proof (which is 6 pages). I think if he has more questions we could continue with discussion.

Comment: @Raphael: Silly.  A link is better than nothing.  If you want, elaborate the answer by yourself instead of blaming a user for posting a useful link.

Comment: @Reza: If we wouldn't answer anything that had been answered before, this would be an empty site indeed.